# Tapkey Web Api gateway timeout

Tags: tapkey

I'm having trouble finding any information about the reliability and uptime of the Tapkey services.

We're seeing multiple failed requests daily to `https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Owners/<owner_id>/Contacts/<contact_id>/Grants` that result in a 504 Gateway Time-out.

This usually resolves itself fairly quickly, but it happens enough that it warrants attention. Are we running into some undocumented feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouter, we saw a couple of latency spikes over the last few days in the Tapkey backend. The problem should have been solved in the meantime, can you confirm? Sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: Hi Markus, I can confirm that the services are responding better. Had 2 timeouts on 9th of september, and nothing over the weekend / today so far.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I notice that some of those calls do take some time to respond (e.g. 5+ seconds), but I rather see them completed than get culled.

Comment: This is continuing as an issue again.

Comment: Can you give some more details about which endpoints are affected and the date/time of the timeouts? We saw a small number of requests failing today around noon (CET) but this has settled again. Do you still see the issues?